# SQL Server Stuff() functions to concatenate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve data for a list of student conditions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DF.DFKEY AS StudentID
    Condition = STUFF((SELECT DISTCINT ',' + DFCOND.ENR_COND 
                       FROM DFCOND
                       WHERE DFCOND.SKEY = DF.DFKEY
                       GROUP BY DFCOND.ENR_COND 
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM 
    DF 
LEFT JOIN
    DFCOND ON df.dfkey = dfcond.skey
WHERE 
    DFCOND.ENR_COND IN ('12', 'CDOC', 'CONSUPP', 'CSEM')
ORDER BY
    DF.DFKEY
```

So in this code. Each student can be assigned with many conditions but I only want to display ones that listed in WHERE IN conditions. DFCOND is the table to stored students condition data and DF is the table to store student information.

My problem is when I run it, all students conditions will be displayed so it skips the 'where in' function. How can I fix it?

For Example,

```
Student ID(DF.KEY) | DFCOND.ENR_COND (Conditions)
  AA12                     70%,12,DOC
```

since '12' is in the "where in" list, I only need

```
Student ID | condition1
  AA12         12
```

These two tables are connected with DF.key and DFCOND.SKEY, they represent Student ID.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: I've updated some info in my question. Sorry, just a beginner for sql. please let me know if more info is needed

Answer (score 0):

You want the filtering in the subquery:

```
select DF.DFKEY as StudentID,
       STUFF((Select Distinct  ',' + DFCOND.ENR_COND 
              from DFCOND
              where DFCOND.SKEY = DF.DFKEY AND
                     DFCOND.ENR_COND in ('12', 'CDOC', 'CONSUPP', 'CSEM')
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as conditions
from DF
order by DF.DFKEY;
```

You also don't need the `JOIN` in the outer query.  Nor the `GROUP BY` in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!! May I ask one more question that I want to only list students have conditions displayed. Now I have the list with a bunch of students with empty conditions because their conditions don't meet the requirements. I want to filter out those students as well.

Comment: A simple method is to make this a subquery and check that `conditions <> ''`.  Alternatively, you can use an `exists` clause to be sure there is at least one match.